# php regex parsing of lines

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I have the following being returned line by line by fetching array from a function.

> [1mSlot Alias UpRate DnRate MinAct
>   [4m/Id Links Links 
>   [0m 1/1 113822003 0 0 1 1/1 , 1/2 , 1/5 , 2/1 , 
>   3/1 , 3/2 , 4/1 , 4/2
>   1/3 432144003 0 0 1 1/3 , 3/3 
>   1/4 128447003 0 0 1 1/4 , 3/4 
>   1/6 123458003 0 0 1 1/6 , 2/5 , 4/8 , 6/6 , 
>   6/25
>   1/9 123445003 0 0 1 1/9 , 1/31, 2/18, 3/9 , 
>   5/8 , 6/22, 6/23, 6/24, 
>   6/26, 7/8 , 7/11, 7/13, 
>   7/14, 8/6 , 8/7 , 8/8 , 
>   8/11, 8/22, 9/11, 9/12

I have the following Regex expressions that work in http://www.regexr.com/ but don't all work in php as intended it seems. Specifically the EfmLinkRegex, the negative lookahead isn't working right. The first three I use preg_match() the Link one I use preg_match_all().

```
$OrderRegex = '([0-9]{4,7}003)';
$GroupRegex = '(^[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2})';
$LinkRegex = '/(?!^[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2})([0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2})/';
```

Current code I'm using:

```
foreach ($Data as $row)
{
    preg_match($OrderRegex, $row, $OrderMatches);
    preg_match($GroupRegex, $row, $GroupMatches);
    preg_match_all($LinkRegex, $row, $LinkMatches);
}
```

What I run in to on line 3 of my example input above is the first "1/1" value is preceded by "[0m " negating the ^ of the regex (which doesn't work anyways at the moment). I also need a way to add in the links from the lines without matching orders to be assigned to that order.

example end result:

```
Order: 113822003
Group: 1/1
Links: 1/1, 1/2, 1/5, 2/1, 3/1, 3/2, 4/1, 4/2

Order: 432144003
Group: 1/3
Links: 1/3, 3/3

Order: 128447003
Group: 1/4
Links: 1/4, 3/4

etc, etc, etc,
```

example end result as array:

Array ( [Group] => Array ( [0] => 1/1 ) [Order] => Array ( [0] => 113822003 ) [Links] => Array ( [0] => 1/1 [1] => 1/2 [2] => 1/5 [3] => 2/1 [4] => 3/1 [5] => 3/2 [6] => 4/1 [7] => 4/2 ) )

I know there is most likely something simple I'm missing here but it is eluding me. If I could perhaps match "Group" minus the ^ only if it precedes the Order somehow else just add it to the Link array?

EDIT:
Found that passing each $row through a "$row = substr( $row, 1, strlen($row) );" seems to have fixed my issue with Group and Link regex strings pulling correct matches, I guess somehow there were invisible characters at the beginnings of some lines not allowing the start of string indicator in regex to work properly.

So now I only need to figure out how to make it so any line that does not contain an "order" adds the links to the previous line's link matches

Comment: I'm not undertanding what output you are looking for. Can you please paste some kind of array for the output you would like? Would you be happy to do it with one regex? Does it have to be line by line?

Comment: PHP's preg_* functions need delimiters such as /.../ or ~...~. In the first and second cases, I think it's eating the () as delimiters. Add ~ delimiters just inside the ' quotes.

Comment: Yes it has to be line by line (or more specifically each line is one entry in an array called "$Data", so I pull it out entry by entry to parse), this is the way the telnet class returns the lines read from the router. Adding /.../ to the other two did not help with the returns.

Comment: The example end result is what I need, you can make it all one array if you want as long as I can get to "order" "group" and "links" I don't really care what format it is.

Comment: Added array example of first example output needed

Comment: Those `[0m`s etc look a lot like terminal control sequences (which typically have an "Escape" character ("`\x1b`") before them).  If possible, you might want to consider making your source not output them.  But at the very least, you can strip them out before you process the data.

Comment: Thanks cHao I went ahead and added a quick substr to pull out the extraneous characters entered by terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you do it in two steps.
step 1 :
use this pattern `^.*?(?=\d+\/\d+)|(, )\v|(\v)\v+|(003)(?: \d+){3}` with `gs` options and replace w/ `$1$2$3` to clean it up.
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/zJ6cT4)

results will look like so

> 1/1 113822003 1/1 , 1/2 , 1/5 , 2/1 , 3/1 , 3/2 , 4/1 , 4/2
>   1/3 432144003 1/3 , 3/3
>   1/4 128447003 1/4 , 3/4
>   1/6 123458003 1/6 , 2/5 , 4/8 , 6/6 , 6/25
>   1/9 123445003 1/9 , 1/31, 2/18, 3/9 , 5/8 , 6/22, 6/23, 6/24, 6/26, 7/8 , 7/11, 7/13, 7/14, 8/6 , 8/7 , 8/8 , 8/11, 8/22, 9/11, 9/12

step 2:
now it is really easy to perform another RegEx and get your desired end results like so
use this pattern `^(\d+\/\d+)\s*(\d{9})\s*([, \/0-9]+)` with `gm` options and replace with `Order: $2\nGroup: $1\nLinks: $3\n`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/kP7kD0)

Comment: I wish I was this awesome with Regex, thank you very much these lead me to the answer I needed. One question, what would you say the most efficient way to do step 1 would be since each line is one entry in an array?

Comment: I don't know php, but I would imagine you use a "for" loop to go through each array values and apply the RegEx on it.